# Does DOORS maintain a history of all the modules I have worked in?

Tags: module, ibm-doors

## Background

I am currently doing a task where I am relinking objects inside a module (Module_B). While relinking, I forgot to include a new "Link_" column to set up the new links for Module_C.  Therefore I erroneously linked to the wrong module (Module_D).  I did not realize this until I looked at both the links to the old module (Module_A) and the new module (Module_D but should be Module_C).  Now all the links inside the Link_Module_A and Link_Module_C columns of Module_B go to nowhere.

I need to figure which module contains my mistake, that is, I want to find which Module was Module_B.

## Question

Is there a way I can find the history of all modules that I have opened in DOORS?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no built-in running history of modules that have been opened for vanilla DOORS.
I know on the database I work on, we created a trigger to log what you're asking for.
Assuming you're not the admin, maybe you can ask your admin if they have something like this implemented on the database you're working on.